# Firebase phone number authentication always returns a null token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate firebase phone number authenticaton into my application using the following link: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

I am using the drop-in solution with Firebase-UI. It seems like phone number authentication is successful but the resultant token & secret are always null. I confirmed that **onActivityResult** got fired with result code as **RESULT_OK**.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly request for the token.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getToken(true)
```